# "detail": "Not found." DRF

Tags: django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

I get "detail": "Not found." when I visit this link
localhost:8000/portal/finalyears/1/members/2
but when I use the following link it shows the details:
localhost:8000/portal/finalyears/1/members/1

My urls.py file contains:

```
    path('finalyears/<int:pk>/members/<int:id>', MemberDetailView.as_view(), name='Members_Detail'),
```

The model "Member" looks like this:

```
class Member(models.Model):
    finalyear = models.ForeignKey(to=FYP, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Student_Id = models.ForeignKey(to=Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Leader_FYP = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Members'

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.finalyear)
```

The API.py Contains:

```
class MemberDetailView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    # lookup_field = "member_pk"

    def get_queryset(self):
        fyp = self.kwargs['pk']
        member = self.kwargs['id']
        return Member.objects.filter(finalyear=fyp,  id=member)

    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
```

I can print the data by the following code

```
from PortalAPI.serializers import MemberSerializer
from PortalAPI.models import Member

for a in Member.objects.filter(finalyear=1, id=2):
...     MemberSerializer(a).data
```

Comment: probably because there is no such member with  id '2'?

Comment: There is a member and it gets printed when I test it with the last code